# Browsermob proxy - how can I modify response using response_interceptor?

Tags: python, selenium, browsermob-proxy

I am using a python [wrapper](https://github.com/AutomatedTester/browsermob-proxy-py) for [browsermob proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/), and I need to modify the server response. But I can't figure out how I can do it. Can anybody give me a working code sample?

The documentation says I can send a javascript code for it, but it does not work for me:

```
server = Server(path=SCRIPT_DIR+"/browsermob-proxy/bin/browsermob-proxy", options={"port": 8888})
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()

proxy.response_interceptor('contents.setTextContents("<html><body>Response successfully intercepted</body></html>")')

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp, proxy=proxy)
browser.get("http://example.com")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In browsermobproxy version 0.7.1, response_interceptor is bugged. You can go to [github](https://github.com/AutomatedTester/browsermob-proxy-py) and get the latest code or you can use this work-around instead of response_interceptor:

```
import requests

url = proxy.host + '/proxy/' + str(proxy.port) + '/filter/response'
headers={'Content-Type':'text/plain'}

filter = "contents.setTextContents('<html><body>Response successfully intercepted</body></html>');"

r = requests.post(url=url, data=filter, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Works like a charm - just don't forget to set proxy on your Firefox profile ;) fp.set_proxy(proxy.selenium_proxy())

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium import webdriver
from browsermobproxy import Server
from pprint import pprint
from time import sleep
import requests


server = Server($PATH_GOES_HERE$)
server.start()


proxy = server.create_proxy()

proxy.new_har('test111')

url = proxy.host + '/proxy/' + str(proxy.port) + '/filter/response'
headers={'Content-Type':'text/plain'}

filter = "response.setTextContents('<html><body>Response successfully intercepted</body></html>');"

r = requests.post(url=url, data=filter, headers=headers)





fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_proxy(proxy.selenium_proxy()) # <---- you forgot this one here ;)
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp, proxy=proxy)
sleep(3)
browser.get("example.com")
```